# The same value in a row not being appended to a 2 dimensional Python list

Tags: python

I've got an issue with appending 2 the same values to the same list from a 1 dimensional list to 2 dimensional list, it seems that only one value is being added to my new list:

Code:

```
grid_list = []
grid_plain_text = """
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
"""

grid_split = grid_plain_text.split()
grid_list = []
grid_list.append([])
counter = 0
index = 0

for item in grid_split:
    counter +=1
    if counter == 21:
        index += 1
        counter = 0
        grid_list.append([])
    else:
        grid_list[index].append(item)

print(grid_list)
```

Output:

> [['08', '02', '22', '97', '38', '15', '00', '40', '00', '75', '04',
>   '05', '07', '78', '52', '12', '50', '77', '91', '08'], [**'49',
>   '99**', '40', '17', '81', '18', '57', '60', '87', '17', '40', '98',
>   '43', '69', '48', '04', '56', '62', '00', '81'], ['31', '73', '55',
>   '79', '14', '29', '93', '71', '40', '67', '53', '88', '30', '03','49',
>   '13', '36', '65', '52', '70'], ['23', '04', '60', '11', '42', '69',
>   '24', '68', '56', '01', '32', '56', '71', '37', '02', '36', '91',
>   '22', '31', '16'], ['51', '67', '63', '89', '41', '92', '36', '54',
>   '22', '40', '40', '28', '66', '33', '13', '80', '24', '47', '32',
>   '60'], ['03', '45', '02', '44', '75', '33', '53', '78','36', '84',
>   '20', '35', '17', '12', '50', '32', '98', '81', '28', '64'], ['67',
>   '10', '26', '38', '40', '67', '59', '54', '70', '66', '18', '38',
>   '64', '70', '67', '26', '20', '68', '02', '62'], ['20', '95', '63',
>   '94', '39', '63', '08', '40', '91', '66', '49', '94', '21', '24',
>   '55', '58', '05', '66', '73', '99'], ['97', '17','78', '78', '96',
>   '83', '14', '88', '34', '89', '63', '72', '21', '36', '23', '09',
>   '75', '00', '76', '44'], ['45', '35', '14', '00', '61', '33', '97',
>   '34', '31', '33', '95', '78', '17', '53', '28', '22', '75', '31',
>   '67', '15'], ['03', '80', '04', '62', '16', '14', '09', '53', '56',
>   '92', '16', '39', '05', '42', '96', '35', '31', '47', '55', '58'],
>   ['24', '00', '17', '54', '24', '36', '29', '85', '57', '86', '56',
>   '00', '48', '35', '71', '89', '07', '05', '44', '44'], ['44', '60',
>   '21', '58', '51', '54', '17', '58', '19', '80', '81', '68', '05',
>   '94', '47', '69', '28', '73', '92', '13'], ['52', '17', '77', '04',
>   '89', '55', '40', '04', '52', '08', '83', '97', '35', '99', '16',
>   '07', '97', '57', '32', '16'], ['26', '79', '33', '27', '98', '66',
>   '88', '36', '68', '87', '57', '62', '20', '72', '03', '46', '33',
>   '67', '46', '55'], ['32', '63', '93', '53', '69', '04', '42', '16',
>   '73', '38', '25', '39', '11', '24', '94', '72', '18', '08', '46',
>   '29'], ['40', '62', '76', '36', '20', '69', '36', '41', '72', '30',
>   '23', '88', '34', '62', '99', '69', '82', '67', '59', '85'], ['04',
>   '36', '16', '20', '73', '35', '29', '78', '31', '90', '01', '74',
>   '31', '49', '71', '48', '86', '81', '16', '23'], ['05', '54', '01',
>   '70', '54', '71', '83', '51', '54', '69', '16', '92', '33', '48',
>   '61', '43', '52', '01', '89', '19'], ['48']]

I can't understand why it's happening or how to correct this issue.

Comment: Your problem actually appears to be that you are skipping values when beginning a new row - check the start of the third row, for example. It should be '49'.

Comment: You are not missing the value because it is a duplicate, but because you are missing the first value for each row.

Comment: When counter is equal to 21, you're not appending that item to the grid_list, and so the 21st item is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need all the logic, just split by new line `\n` and then by space

```
grid_list = [x.split(' ') for x in grid_plain_text.strip().split('\n')]
```

Answer (score 3):

When you read the 21st element each time, you have:

```
if counter == 21:
    index += 1
    counter = 0
    grid_list.append([])
```

This resets the counter and increments the index as it should, but it also skips the 21st element itself. You need to add this element to the list at the incremented index. This can be done as:

```
if counter == 21:
    index += 1
    counter = 0
    grid_list.append([item])
```